# Expression describing a scene behind an open door, that's angled out of my vision

Tags: phrase-requests

Say I'm in a large room with a door. I can see the door, but I can't see what's beyond it, because it's angled out of my vision:

[image]

(Here the red box is the location of the door.)

Is there a word/phrase that describes this situation, possibly referencing a door?

Comment: What's on the other side of the door is _out of your field of view_  (the door itself isn't).

Comment: Can you provide an example sentence using the word/phrase? See the details on [phrase requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/phrase-requests/info).

Comment: @StuartF the sentence is not likely to be helpful unfortunately, e.g. *they reached a room with a [door] at the far end*. I need to describe at some point that what's beyond the door is not visible from where they're standing.

Comment: Is the door closed, ajar perhaps? Obscuring/obstructing the view certainly. Could you provide a bit more context.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. Neither. My characters reach the room with the door, which is originally closed. Someone opens the door and walks in, closing the door behind them. The characters really want to know what's behind the door, but they can't see it because it is a [door].

Comment: So, the doorframe is at such an oblique angle to the viewer as to make what's beyond the door unseen. Hmmm. That's a tough thing to put in a two-word phrase.

Comment: "not visible to us or to me"

Comment: Whatever you can't see is "out of view", but I don't think there's a specific phrase for this particular relationship with the door.